# Failure to transfer aopalliance

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I have just started with creating a spring maven project.

I am getting the following error in my pom.xml:

> Failure to transfer aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0 from 
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository,  resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central  has elapsed or updates are forced.

Original error:

```
Could not transfer artifact aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0 from/to central 
The operation was cancelled.
```

My pom.xml is like this :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>AlertProj1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

Comment: just a small suggestion for pasting code in Question - have a look at this [Doc](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make your question and sample code more readable. When you have a block of code, first paste it in editor like Notepad++, select all and Press `Tab` then select all, copy and paste into new line of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is maven import error occurred because you don't have all those dependencies and their transitive dependencies in your local repository.

To fix this, you need to force Maven to pull all dependencies. Open Command Prompt and navigate to the root folder of your project where `pom.xml` file exists. Run below command:

```
mvn package
```

This will download the missing dependencies from remote repository.

Comment: How to do this in windows? I am using Spring Tool Suite

Comment: Press Win+R, type cmd and press Enter to Open command prompt. Then `cd C:\Users\Username\workspace\projectName` this should be your Project path and then type above command.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I cancelled the the download of one of my project dependencies.

Following steps worked for me:
1. Remove the dependency(that you cancelled download) from pom.xml and
    build(package or install).
2. Add the dependency back to pom.xml 
3. Build(package or install) again.